# Is there a SE where I can ask a mechanical engineering question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a mechanical engineering question and see that there is an Areas 51 mechanical engineering exchange proposed but not active yet. I've scrolled through the list of SE sections but haven't seen one that is clearly appropriate. I thought maybe Physics but from checking out the questions, it seems not.

Any suggestions? The gist of the question concerns load bearing with a machine I am designing.

Comment: There is a [deleted Mechanical Engineering proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44908/mechanical-engineering) as well. [This appears to be the existing proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60942/).

Answer (score 9):

Check out https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-engineering

The Engineering section has mechanical engineering tags.